# Why is this binding not working on angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller setup like so:

```
.controller( 'ProductsCtrl', function ProductsController( $scope, ProductRes, $state, $http ) {

  $scope.updateThing = function() {
    $scope.thing = true;
  };
...
```

in the view I have:

```
<button ng-click='updateThing()'>CLICK THIS TO HIDE THE P</button>

<p ng-hide="{{thing}}">hide this when button clicked</p>
```

My other bindings work such as input filters and what not. So, it tells me there is something wrong with this particular setup...

Answer (score 6):

Should be `ng-hide="thing"`, afaik

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
ng-hide="{{thing}}"
```

to this:

```
ng-hide="thing"
```